# Populate select options in a haml view with JSON data

Tags: json, sinatra, haml

how can I populate `%select` options in the `haml` view with `JSON` parameters I have in `sinatra` controller.

In the `sinatra` controller I have:

```
response = JSON.parse(curl_resp)
nestedData = response["data"][0]
  nestedData.each do |c|
  names =  c["attributes"]["names"]
end
return haml :newPage, :locals => {:name => example: name in names}
```

and this the `%select` options in `newPage.haml` view:

```
%select{:name => "select names"}
  %option{:value => "id1"} #{locals[:name]}.[0]
  %option{:value => "id2"} #{locals[:name]}.[1]
  %option{:value => "id3"} #{locals[:name]}.[2]
  %option{:value => "id4"} #{locals[:name]}.[3]
```

this is a sample `JSON` I get from `curl`:

```
{"data":[
  {"id":"id1","attributes":{"name":"gnu"}},
  {"id":"id2","attributes":{"name":"Alice"}},
  {"id":"id3","attributes":{"name":"testsubject"}},
  {"id":"id4","attributes":{"name":"testissuer"}}
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to iterate over the entire dataset and display `<option>` tags, you can use something like:

```
# app.rb

get '/' do
  # This is obtained from JSON.parse-ing the incoming data. I've used the JSON
  # value directly
  @json = {
    data:[
      {id:"id1",attributes:{name:"gnu"}},
      {id:"id2",attributes:{name:"Alice"}},
      {id:"id3",attributes:{name:"testsubject"}},
      {id:"id4",attributes:{name:"testissuer"}}
    ]
  }
  haml :index
end
```

And in the view:

```
 / index.haml

 %select
   = @json[:data].each do |data_item|
     %option{ value: data_item[:id] }
       = data_item[:attributes][:name]
```

This way, you don't have to hard-code the number of option tags in the template, which would make it more complicated.